# Userscript - Add a Close-Icon mouseover to Images

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, mouseover

I am writing a **Userscript** for **Greasemonkey** to have an **MouseOver Effect** on all **Images** with class="png" which will be a close-Button( [image: Close Button] ) in the top-right corner.

If I could edit the original HTML File I would do this: http://jsfiddle.net/6pjF4/55/ (This one shows the output Im going for)

But since I can't, this is my current - not working - approach: http://jsfiddle.net/6pjF4/54/

Is it possible to get the Close-Button into this function?

```
elem.onmouseover = function() {
        play.style.display = "inline";
```

That way I wouldn't need the image in the HTML file

Thank you very much for your time and energy putting in reading (and answering)! Much appreciated-

Answer (score 0):

The best way to position that button is to:

- Add the button to the `body` element.  This is important.
- Use `position:absolute`  like you are.
- Get the real position of the element you are looking at. This is a bit tricky.
- Using that, set `top` and `left` position if your button to manually place it.

Getting the element position is tricky, so I'll give you this:

```
 var getElementPosition = function(obj) {
    var curleft =0;
    var curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
      curleft = obj.offsetLeft;
      curtop = obj.offsetTop;
      while (obj = obj.offsetParent) {
        curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
        curtop += obj.offsetTop;
      }       
    }
    return [curleft,curtop];
  }
```

Comment: "Add the button to the body element." The body of the HTML? I cannot do that, its just an userscript which will change the appereance of a specific website. Or can a userscript have a body too?

Comment: Even userscripts can do a `document.getElementByTagName("body")[0].append(newElement);`